# PHP append string with return

Tags: php, json

I have a function in PHP that takes the JSON output and returns it. What I'm trying to do is return that StdClass Object with some strings around it. So to be clear, I need to wrap $json in 'JSON_CALLBACK()'. Since it's not possible to append strings around it, I'm looking for another way to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Note: 'JSON_CALLBACK()' is not a function, it's just a string.

Here's my code:

```
    public function showOutput() {

    try {
        $oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec);
        $oauth->fetch($api_base . '/uItems');
        $json = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse());
        //return ($json);

    }
    catch(OAuthException $E) {
        return($E);
    }

    echo "JSON_CALLBACK(";
    return($json);
    echo ")"; //wont do anything since return is already called so how can i append this with return?

}
```

Comment: calling `return` ends the function. Nothing can happen after return, within that function.

Comment: So do you want to return an object to a calling function, or output a string to the browser? You cant do both - please clarify what you are trying to do

Comment: I'm aware of that. I've edited my question to be more clear. How can i append the bracket?

Comment: why do you "return $json" ? how does the caller uses the returned value ? You are confusing echo and return things I guess

Comment: What exactly are you expecting the return to do? It won't output anything. It just ends the function and returns a value. It won't echo anything. You are trying to do two separate things. echo and return. Do you want to echo something or do you want the function to return it?

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear - I want to return the $json object wrapped around like this - JSON_CALLBACK($json)  so JSON_CALLBACK is wrapped around it.

Comment: ok, then don't json_decode the json string. It is already in a json format and you can just wrap that with your callback and return it.

Comment: You cannot wrap a string around an object. Do you want to call a function 'JSON_CALLBACK' with the $json object as parameter?

Comment: Also, you have three returns in there. Your function would never reach the code where you are trying to wrap with `JSON_CALLBACK()` because you return in both the try and catch. So if there was an error or not, you would have already returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is you code fixed with comments to help understand the changes.

```
public function showOutput() {
    try {
        $oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec);
        $oauth->fetch($api_base . '/uItems');

        //don't decode since it is already json
        //$json = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse());

        //don't return here, you will never reach the bottom of the code
        //return ($json);

        //get the json string instead
        $json = $oauth->getLastResponse();
    }
    catch(OAuthException $E) {
        //you can leave this return in here just in case there is a problem
        //with oauth. This will stop the function if there was an error.
        return($E);
    }

    //since this wasn't decoded, it is a string of json.
    return "JSON_CALLBACK({$json})";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return will be the last line in your function

```
 echo "JSON_CALLBACK(";
 return($json);// control will return back.
 echo ")";// this will not work
```

Any line after `return` will not be executed.

So,

```
return "JSON_CALLBACK($json)";
```

One thing i didnt understand is that your flow will not come to this line at all.

You have return in `try` as well as `catch`

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: I am aware of this, you're not answering my question.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I have commented out the return under try already. I need the JSON decoded and wrapped around JSON_CALLBACK(). Without the JSON being a string, I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps ?

```
echo "JSON_CALLBACK(" . $json . ")";
return $json;
```

Comment: This would convert the StdClass to string.

Comment: @aqq then don't json_decode it if you want it to be a string. Return the string that is the json.

Comment: @aqq angular is client side. there is no need to decode the json server side. On the client side it needs the raw json string,  not the php decoded object.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn It doesn't work for me because then it outputs JSON with \ before every double quote which is unreadable. This is why I need the JSON output decoded.

Comment: Technically, then it is not valid json. But to fix it, if `JSON_CALLBACK` is a js function that will get run, you would want to do something like `JSON_CALLBACK(JSON.parse("{$json}"))`. If run in JS, that will parse the json to a JS object and pass that result to the `JSON_CALLBACK`.

Answer (score -1):

`echo` prints to the screen, while `return` just returns a value.

There isn't any point of enclosing return in text. It doesn't make sense.

If you do something like:

```
echo 'JSON_CALLBACK()';
return $json;
```

It would have same effect what your program would have given if somehow last line also executed, as return doesn't print anything.

If you just want to print, print in the calling function.